# Issue in reading paginated API data using ADF

Tags: azure, rest, etl, azure-data-factory, genesys

I am trying to read the data from a paginated API using ADF copy activity. While accessing the API at first time, only the base URL is used(without any query params). When API returns the data, it will have a key called cursor with some token. This has to be passed as query string to get the next page. How to implement this using ADF?. How to append "***?cursor=***" in the base URL and then add cursor value from API response

First Page : {{Base URL}} #returns a JSON with a key called cursor
From Second Page : {{Base URL}}?cursor = {{value of cursor key in JSON Response}}

I have tried using Query Parameters inside the Copy Activity of pagination. But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use web activity to the cursor value and pass it to the relative URL in copy activity.

1. You can first make a call with the base URL using web activity.

[image]

2. Parameterize the relative URL in the dataset.

[image]

3. Connect web activity to copy data activity and pass the web activity output required value to the copy activity dataset parameters to run the URL with cursor value.

Ex: `@concat('?cursor=',activity('Web1').output.cursor)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the Web Activity has a limitation to fetch only less than 4 MB of data. Data I am trying to read for each page goes beyond that. So this approach won't work